# how to toggle between styles using Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, toggle

I have a div with class of `.ban2` and id of `#banner2`.

I want to change the border-radius property of this div whenever I click on the div itself. Like when iI click it for the first time the border-radius becomes 0 and when I click again it goes back to `50% 0 0 50%`.

I want to toggle between these 2 styles. in my `.ban2Toggle` class I have all the styles included, but the border radius is 0.

it is only working once like when I click it for the first time the border radius becomes 0. The next time I click it I don't know how to get it back to normal.

```
.banner .ban2{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 63vh;
  background: #5a0980;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
  transform: scaleY(1.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

$('#banner2').on('click', function(){
  $('#banner2').removeClass('ban2');
  $('#banner2').addClass('ban2Toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), you must use

```
$(element).toggleClass('className');
```

It will automatically add and remove it for you.

For [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), you must use

```
element.classList.toggle('className');
```

It will automatically add and remove it for you.

**Example Snippet (Run)**

```js
$('#banner2').on('click', function() {
  $('#banner2').toggleClass('ban2Toggle');
});
```

```css
.banner .ban2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 63vh;
  background: #5a0980;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
  transform: scaleY(1.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.banner .ban2.ban2Toggle {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <div id="banner2" class="ban2">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i already have .ban2 class present. i want it to be removed and be replaced by .ban2Toggle

Answer (score 1):

Following [the answer from BOZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64732077/14566522) you need to do it like this:

html:

```
<div id="banner2" class="ban2"></div>
```

script:

```
$('#banner2').on('click', function(){
  $('#banner2').toggleClass('ban2');
  $('#banner2').toggleClass('ban2Toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

take a variable of naming flag=false;
When you click on the button change the state of the flag variable to true
When the flag is true make border radius 0 using conditional rendering
When click again make flag false again
When the flag is false make border radius 50 using again conditional rendering